# Porque o evento de click não funciona?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button">click</button>
  <p></p>

  <script>
  
    var botao = window.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    var paragrafo = window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

    botao.onclick = function() {
      paragrafo.textContent = "Você clicou!";
    };

    botao.onclick = function() {
      window.alert("Você clicou!");
    };

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Então tenho este código o meu problema é que o primeiro `onclick` não funciona apenas o segundo `onclick`, porque isso tá acontecendo e tem como executar os dois?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste, caso você está usando dois `onclick`, então basicamente o segundo `onclick` que você definiu sera o que vai ser executado o segundo `onclick` vai substituir o primeiro, assim o primeiro `onclick` não executara apenas o segundo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button">click</button>
  <p></p>

  <script>
  
    var botao = window.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    var paragrafo = window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

    botao.onclick = function() {
      paragrafo.textContent = "Você clicou!";
    };

    botao.onclick = function() {
      window.alert("Você clicou!");
    };

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Para isso não acontecer use em vez de `onclick` use o `addEventListener`, assim você podera chamar quantos evento de `click` você quiser!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button">click</button>
  <p></p>

  <script>
  
    var botao = window.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    var paragrafo = window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

    botao.addEventListener("click", function() {
      paragrafo.textContent = "Você clicou!";
    });

    botao.addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.alert("Você clicou!");
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No Javascript puro o onClick é usado da seguinte forma:

```
botao.addEventListener("click", function(){
      alert('clicado!');
});
```

Caso tenha mais dúvidas link para referência: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp